# Recover data from a corrupt Bootcamp Windows partition?

Tags: windows, mac, partitioning, data-recovery, boot-camp

I recently sent my Macbook Pro in for repairs after a crash (Windows partition not recognized, after working well for a year), and they replaced the logic board and HD, the former of which was dead and the latter of which "wasn't running very well". I got the HD back, and have been trying to get data off it; the problem is, most of my data was stored on my Windows Bootcamp partition, which I can now see - but not access.

This is the info I got off it, since Disk Utility still recognizes it.

```
Mount Point       : /Volumes/BOOTCAMP
Capacity          : 116.7 GB (125,294,346,240 Bytes)
Format            : Windows NT File System (NTFS)
Available         : 26.6 GB (28,521,467,904 Bytes)   
Used              : 90.1 GB (96,772,874,240 Bytes)
Number of Files   : 138,674
Owners Enabled    : No
Number of Folders : 0
```

I feel as if there should be a way to recover data from the drive, since it obviously still...exists and is recognized. But using `Verify` in Disk Utility returns a `Verify volume failed: invalid request`, and I can't otherwise see any files, since there are apparently 0 folders.

Does anyone have any recommendations for data recovery software that works in Mac? I can't just run Windows from an external drive because the HD with the Bootcamp on it is Mac-formatted.

Answer (score 1):

I've always used Linux Live CD's to recover data from drives. You may try this and see if you can recover the files...

go here: http://www.ubuntu.com/desktop/get-ubuntu/download
follow the steps to create the CD and go to step #3 Try it!

You'll be able to boot into Ubuntu directly from the CD, it should automatically mount the drive and you'll be able to browse it and hopefully remove the items you need from the Bootcamp partition.